# (LibGDX) Android app crashes when creating FrameBuffers

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I received a crash report from Google play store for one of my Android apps created using LibGDX.

```
Huawei MediaPad T3 7 (hwbg2), Android 6.0

java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.GLFrameBuffer.build (GLFrameBuffer.java:233)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.GLFrameBuffer.<init> (GLFrameBuffer.java:87)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.<init> (FrameBuffer.java:51)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.GLFrameBuffer$FrameBufferBuilder.build (GLFrameBuffer.java:474)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.createFrameBuffer (FrameBuffer.java:72)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.createFrameBuffer (FrameBuffer.java:56)
  at MY_PACKAGE.editor.Backup.<init> (Backup.java:21)
  at MY_PACKAGE.editor.EditingImage.<init> (EditingImage.java:277)
  at MY_PACKAGE.screens.EditingScreen.<init> (EditingScreen.java:227)
  at MY_PACKAGE.screens.Screens.<init> (Screens.java:42)
  at MY_PACKAGE.MAIN_CLASS$2.run (MAIN_CLASS.java:121)
  at MY_PACKAGE.screens.SplashScreen.render (SplashScreen.java:93)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render (Game.java:46)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame (AndroidGraphics.java:495)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun (GLSurfaceView.java:1599)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run (GLSurfaceView.java:1295)
```

Code at GLFrameBuffer.java:233

```
if (result == GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT)
            throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: incomplete attachment");
```

EditingImage.java is as follows

```
class EditingImage{

    public static final int pixmapWidth = 1024;

    public EditingImage{
        frameBuffer = FrameBuffer.createFrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB888,pixmapWidth,pixmapWidth,false);

        ....

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
          final Backup backup = new Backup(pixmapWidth);
          availableBackups.add(backup);
        }
    }
}
```

Backup.java is as follow

```
Backup(int width){
    frameBuffer = FrameBuffer.createFrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB888, width, width, false);
    ....
}
```

The app has crashed inside Backup.java when creating the FrameBuffer (after how many loops I don't know).

As you can see FrameBuffer created in EditingImage has not crashed and it has been executed before instantiating Backup objects.

It works normally on my phone (Huawei Y6II). Also have tested in some Samsung phones.

Please help!

Comment: So you're creating 51 framebuffers? Do you need so many? The system might be running out of resources.

Comment: The app is a coloring app. Every time the user color I keep a backup copied to a backup FrameBuffer using the main FrameBuffer so that the user can "undo" and "redo". As there are 50 Backup FrameBuffers the user can undo for 50 times.

Comment: @Columbo If I reduce Backups to 20 then will it work fine? I don't have the device with which the app crashes to test this.

Comment: Not sure - I expect it has a good chance of working if you reduce to 20. Perhaps you should catch the exception, and use that to limit the number of undo buffers available. An alternative is to try to rework the code so that instead of each of your backups being a framebuffer, they're just textures, or even images saved to your app's temp folder. I'm not familiar with libgdx at all though so can't offer much guidance on how to achieve that though.

Comment: Check on memory usage for desktop version. I.e. on windows, mac or where ever you do development run your app, open some task manager and check of memory your app is allocating. Is it constantly growing (you have some memory leak) or it's at constant level (expected behavior ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 year 11 months I found the issue.

According to the documentation:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html

It says for the format which is passed as the parameter in the constructor should be RGB565 or RGBA4444 or RGB5_A1

> format - the format of the color buffer; according to the OpenGL ES
> 2.0 spec, only RGB565, RGBA4444 and RGB5_A1 are color-renderable

Where as in my case i have used RGB888